# Nginx try_files not working regexp

Tags: nginx, location

I created a location in my nginx configuration file:

```
location ~* ^/resize/(.*)/(\d+)/(\d+)/(.*)\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$ {
    try_files /var/image-gallery/php/web/assert/$1/$4_$2_$3.$5 /resize.php?storage=$1&width=$2&height=$3&file=$4&ext=$5;
}
```

If file exists, I want nginx to return it. Otherwise I want to run a script which is supposed to stream a file content in the end.

HTTP request example: `http://host:8000/resize/storage3/100/100/28f686ecb64bbb0c90d824a4be08a1e9.jpeg`

File location:

```
$ file /var/image-gallery/php/web/assert/storage3/28f686ecb64bbb0c90d824a4be08a1e9_100_100.jpeg
/var/image-gallery/php/web/assert/storage3/28f686ecb64bbb0c90d824a4be08a1e9_100_100.jpeg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 100x100, frames 3
```

Why nginx cannot see the file on disk?

Comment: Could you also show us the nginx logs?

Comment: @IvanVelichko, see my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Nginx doesn't use absolute paths.

Fix:

```
location ~* ^/resize/(.*)/(\d+)/(\d+)/(.*)\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$ {
   root /var/image-gallery/php/web/assert;
   try_files /$1/$4_$2_$3.$5 /resize.php?storage=$1&width=$2&height=$3&file=$4&ext=$5;
}
```